Cached files around 2-3GB even after restarting
So I was in my class yesterday and decided to check up my system through activity monitor, I saw that the cached was in the gb section, so I thought why not restart the system, once back on, I open the monitor app to see its a little over 3gb, after a bit it goes down around 2.5 to 2.7gb
It is in the memory section of Activity Monitor between Memory Used and Swap Files
I only restarted the system expecting cached files to be in 0
